# AnyLogic + Pypeline : running Python scripts before each experiment run

Tags: python, simulation, anylogic

I would like to run an external Python script before each AnyLogic experiment run. I tried to follow what is explained here (https://www.anylogic.com/upload/pdf/q-and-a-with-writeups.pdf). The author of the document suggests to initialize the PyCommunicator object through a variable in the simulation page. I tried to do that by when I run the model, the variable is at null value.
[image]

[image]

In order to understand if I made some mistake in the definition of the parameters for the constructor of the PyCommunicator object, I went in the Main agent where I have another PyCommunicator object dragged from the palette and set through the properties panel, and I tried to manually create a PyCommunicator object copying the exact same value of the already existing object in the constructor. Here the code:

```
//py is the PyCommunicator object created by drag and drop from Palette
//py2 is the manually created PyCommunicator object

System.out.println("Py object: "+py);
System.out.println("Enable: "+py.enable);
System.out.println("Load last config: "+py.loadLastWorkingConfig);
System.out.println("Python command type: "+py.pythonCommandType);
System.out.println("Python command: "+py.pythonCommand);
System.out.println("Python executable path: "+py.pythonExecPath);
System.out.println("Throw error: "+py.throwErrorOnFailedAttempt);
System.out.println("Redirect output: "+py.redirectPyOutput);

PyCommunicator py2 = new PyCommunicator(py.enable,py.loadLastWorkingConfig,py.pythonCommandType,py.pythonCommand,py.pythonExecPath,py.throwErrorOnFailedAttempt,py.redirectPyOutput);
System.out.println("Py2 object: "+py2);
```

Also in this case, the manually created object is null. This is what I receive at console:

```
Py object: Python 3.11.0
C:\...\python.exe
Enable: true
Load last config: false
Python command type: PYTHON_PATH
Python command: null
Python executable path: C:\...\python.exe
Throw error: false
Redirect output: true
Py2 object: null
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: The question was solved in a GitHub issue of the library. You can check on that:

https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/AnyLogic-Pypeline/issues/43